# Conditional probability problem: $n$ letters carrying the numbers $1,...,n$ are arranged randomly

Tags: probability

> $n$ letters with the numbers $1,...,n$ written on them are arranged randomly, and than are opened one by one.
>
> Let $k \leq n$. Given that the number written on the $k$-th letter was the highest one out of the numbers written on the first $k$ letters, what is the probability that the number written on the $k$-th letter is $n$?

My try:

$A_i^j$ - the number $j$ is written on the $i$-th letter

$B$ - the number written on the $k$-th letter is $n$

$P(A_k^n)= \frac {P(B\,|\,A_k^n)\,P(A_k^n)}{P(B)}$

$P(B\,|\,A_k^n)=1$

$P(A_k^n)=\frac {1}{n}$

$P(B)=\Sigma_{j=1}^n P(B\,|\,A_k^j)\,P(A_k^j)=\Sigma_{j=k}^n P(B\,|\,A_k^j)\,P(A_k^j)=\Sigma_{j=k}^n \frac {(j-1)!}{(j-k)!}\,\frac {1}{n}$

I'm trying to express $P(A_k^n)$ solely as a function of $n$.

Is there a way to further simplify the sum I got for $P(B)$ or maybe there is a whole different approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All permutations of the same set of letters that constitute the first $k$ letters are equally likely.  Therefore, we can ignore the fact that the highest number among those $k$ letters happened to be on the last ($k$-th) of those letters.

Then the problem becomes finding the probability that the highest among those $k$ letters is $n$.  But that is trivially the probability that $n$ appears among the first $k$ letters, and the probability of that is
$$
\frac{k}{n}
$$